# About socket recv and char[] in C++

Tags: c++, sockets

I am creating a program that can get package and print it to console by C++.
I set the char array to 1024 like :

```
char* buffer = new char[1024];
```

When I get a message is not exactly 1024 character, there is many unknown character on the end of my message because of the empty space in the array. What can I do?

More information (I dont know if it is useful)

The socket is sent by a Java program

```
Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 27555);

BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
out.write("I am your client :D");
out.flush();
```

And the server is written by C++ console application

```
char* recvData = new char[1024];
recv(socket, recvData, strlen(recvData), 0);
cout << recvData << endl;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three problems with the code:

- `recvData` is unitialised when passed to `strlen()`. `strlen()` determines the length of the buffer when it finds a null terminating character, which could be within the buffer or outside. The size of the buffer, less one for terminating null character, should be passed as the maximum number of bytes to read.
- the result of `recv()` is not queried. The code will use `recvData` even if the `recv()` failed, which is a bug.
- `recv()` does not null terminate the buffer.

Save the result of `recv()` and if not `-1` use it as an index into `recvData` to insert the null terminating character.

Alternatively, as this is c++ use a `std::vector<char>` and to manage dynamic memory allocation for you (if dynamic memory allocation is really required):

```
std::vector<char> recvData(1025); // Default initializes all elements to 0.
int result = recv(socket, recvData.data(), recvData.size() - 1);
if (result != -1)
{
    std::cout << recvData.data() << std::endl;
}
```

Remember that data sent via sockets it just a stream of bytes, it is not separated into distinct messages. This means that:

```
out.write("I am your client :D");
```

*might* not be read by a single call to `recv()`. Equally:

```
out.write("I am your client :D");
out.write("OK");
```

*might* be read by a single call to `recv()`. It is the programmer's responsibility to implement a protocol if message-based processing is required.

Answer (score 5):

`strlen` counts the number of bytes until a null (`'\0'`) character is encountered.  There is no guarantee that data returned by a single `recv` call wil be nul-terminated so you'll need to check the number of bytes returned then add your own terminator.

```
char* recvData = new char[1024];
int bytes = recv(socket, recvData, 1023, 0);
if (bytes == -1) {
    cout << "error on recv" << endl;
}
else {
    recvData[bytes] = '\0';    
    cout << recvData << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`recvData` is not **null terminated**, so result of `strlen()` is undefined in this case. you have to do something like the following:

```
int len = 1024;
char *recvData = new char[len + 1];
int lenRead = recv(socket, recvData, len, 0);
if (lenRead < len)
    recvData[lenRead] = '\0';
else
    recvData[len] = '\0'; 
cout << recvData << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this obvious? :)

Just send the length of the string first or terminate the string "properly" (by sending a `\0` after the end of your string; I guess that's something Java isn't doing here).

But overall, you should include the "packet length" anyway, because you might want to ensure there's enough free space before writing to the buffer (using `strlen()` on an uninitialized array is usually a bad idea).